# Setting serialization property at runtime

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

On serializing MyObject, I want to include or not include null properties in Attributes class deciding at runtime. What is best possible way to do that?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class MyObject {
  private String property1;
  private DateTime property2;
  private Attributes attributes;
}

@Data
public class Attributes {
  private String property1;
  private String property2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jackson 2.8, you can use the new "config overrides" functionality (at high level discussed f.ex [here](https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/jackson-2-8-features-5fc692887944#.j5tartyt1)), to specify equivalent of the annotation, like so:

```
mapper.configOverride(Attributes.class)
    // first value for value itself (POJO); second value only relevant
    // for structured types like Map/Collection/array/Optional
    .setInclude(JsonInclude.Value.construct(Include.NON_NULL, null));
```

(along with a few other aspects formerly only available using annotations)

Note, however, that as with annotations, this settings is not something that can be changed after initial setting: it must be defined for `ObjectMapper` once and further changes are not going to have effect.
If you need differently configured mappers you need to create different instances.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possibilities, depending on how fine grained your runtime decision control needs to be.

- If **the behaviour is totally custom at runtime**, you can use your own custom filters that can do complex decisions to either serialize a field or not. A filter will look something like this:

  ```
  PropertyFilter myFilter = new SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {
      @Override public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {

          boolean needsSerialization = needsSerializationBasedOnAdvancedRuntimeDecision((MyValueObject) pojo, writer.getName());

             if (needsSerialization){
                  writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
             }

      }

      @Override protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) { return true; }
      @Override protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) { return true; }
  };
  ```

  Where your serialization decisions can be handled on a property by property basis, for example:

  ```
  private boolean needsSerializationBasedOnAdvancedRuntimeDecision(MyValueObject myValueObject, String name) {
      return !"property1".equals(name) || ( myValueObject.getProperty1() == null && property1NullSerializationEnabled );
  }
  ```

  You can then apply the filters you want as follows:

  ```
  FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("myFilter", myFilter);

  String json = new ObjectMapper().writer(filters).writeValueAsString(myValueObject);
  ```
- if **the behaviour is the same for a property of a class**, annotate *that property* with `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`

  ```
  public class MyObject {

      @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) 
      private String property1;

      private String property2;
  }
  ```
- if **the behaviour is the same for a full class** (e.g. Attributes), configure the class, either with `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` or with the config overrides [StaxMan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40855838/1960816) described

  ```
   @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) 
   public class Attributes {
      private String property1;
      private String property2;
   }
  ```
- if **the behaviour is the same for all classes currently mapped**: configure the mapper, as [franjavi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40819835/1960816) did

Answer (score 0):

You can change that behaviour in the mapper:

```
if (noNull) {
   mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
} else {
   mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.ALWAYS);
}
```

Comment: But i need to do conditional including null only in `Attributes` class and not in `MyObject` class.

Comment: This might not work if class is having JsonIgnore annotation already as objectMapper setting is considered global and the class having that annotation will get the preference